# Getting newest object with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

How can I use ajax to get the newest made object in Ruby on rails?

Say I have two models called Books and chapters. When I make a new chapter I want to update my chapter list.

My current ajax looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/books/:books_id/chapters',
    success: function(data) {
        $("body").append(data);
    }
});
```

But this returns all books with all chapters. 
How do I filter it down to just "The latest books latest chapter" ?

Comment: edit you db query man :)

Comment: did you define associations between models?

Answer (score 0):

Ajax isn't the issue.  This url

```
'/books/:books_id/chapters'
```

will be interpreted by your routes.rb file which will choose a controller and action to handle the request.

**EDIT**: you need to plug an actual id in there.  Currently you're just sending through a string ":books_id" which isn't going to help.  Your javascript should be something like this:

```
//get the book id from somewhere, eg the event which 
//triggered this ajax call.  I've just hard-coded a value in here.
var bookId = 123;
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/books/"+bookId+"/chapters",
    success: function(data) {
        $("body").append(data);
    }
});
```

This action will "do some stuff" and then (hopefully) send some text back to the ajax action (such as the html associated with a record or a set of records).

So, you need to look at the action which handles the request.  Is this actually the right action for what you want to achieve?  If it's the right action, is it doing the right thing?

**EDIT**:
If you're following convention, that url would normally return all the chapters associated with the book with id `bookId`.  You could write a new action like "newest" to return just the newest record, or send through a parameter and then change the behaviour of the action if it gets that parameter etc.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a route to a method in the controller which returns the most recent object which you can then use in your ajax call.

ajax - be sure to pass in the book_id to the url.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: '/books/' + book_id' + '/last_chapter',
  success: function(data) {
    $("body").append(data);
  }
```

});

controller

```
def last_chapter
  Chapter.order(created_at: :desc).limit(1)
end
```

routes

```
resources :books do
  member do 
    get '/last_chapter/', to: 'chapters#last_chapter', as: 'last_chapter'
  end
end
```

Comment: I get the: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" from the /last_chapter  url. 

I put the in the books controller.
`def last_chapter
  Chapter.order(created_at: :desc).limit(1)
end`

I tried the routes both like this
`resources :books do
  :chapters do 
    get '/last_chapter/', to: 'chapters#most_recent', as: 'last_chapter'
  end
end`

and like this

`resources :books do
    get '/last_chapter/', to: 'chapters#most_recent', as: 'last_chapter'
  :chapters 
end`

Comment: Sorry there was an error in my route which I've now updated. However you want to put the last_chapter method in the chapters_controller as that is where the route is going. If you run rake routes in the terminal, it will show you the routes and the corresponding controller#action.

Comment: Now I tried to add the 
def last_chapter (but I changed the name to most_recent) to the chapterscontroller. The console now says: 500 (Internal Server Error)

The terminal says:
`Started GET "/books/99/last_chapters" for 
Processing by chaptersController#most_recent as */*
Parameters: {"books_id"=>"99"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 16ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template chapters/most_recent, application/most_recent with {...}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/cols/railsapp/app/views"
):`

Comment: Oh! didn't see your answer before I answered again. I'll try the updated version! :)

Comment: Still gets the Completed 500 Internal Server Error.

`resources :books do
  member do 
    get '/last_chapter/', to: 'chapters#last_chapter', as: 'last_chapter'
  end
end`

Is the member supposed to be chapter ?  and should it have : infront ?